# How to decide the current point reach on google map?

Tags: google-maps

How to decide the current point reach on google map?

I have a list of points (pickup points) of a route that I want to show in my google map with polyline.

Now i have to get the current location of bus after every 30 second, so now how we can assume that our current location is reach on our pickup up point location. because they may be differ in some point in lat & long. I want to send sms for the peoples whose pickup point is next pick up point. so need to find out that the current pickup point reach.

Also there is some scenario when bus not goes on predefined route? How can we do this type of functionality?

Comment: One single question mark is enough, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

err, i dont really understand your entire question, but i think what your asking for is how to know when an object (bus) moving on a route has reached a destination.

I would do it this way. I would define a certain tolerance, maybe 10 meters. If the distance between the destination and my current location is less than 10 meters, that would mean i have reached.

About the bus moving without a route. I reckon you could "tether" the bus to the nearest known node. The bus "tether" would pass from node to node depending on which node is closest to the bus.